# Split column and generate dataframe

Tags: r

Say you read a dataframe in R like so:

```
df <- read.table('test.txt', sep = '\t')
```

At some point I want to traverse the dataframe and split one particular column on a delimiter to create another dataframe to traverse.

So, for a dataframe like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    ...    colN
name1    value1;value2;value3;value4   anothervalue ...
```

How can I split `col2` to generate a dataframe consisting of `value1, value2, etc...`?

Comment: Like so? `t(data.frame(strsplit(df$col2, ';')))` This will give you a matrix but you can easily convert that to a data.frame with `data.frame()`or `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: @Majo `non-character argument` in strsplit

Comment: try `df$col2 <- as.character(df$col2)` before splitting? Sounds like df$col2 is a factor. Your could also pass `stringsAsFactors=F`to `read.table()`

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(df, "col2", ";")` should do it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the delimiter is a semicolon:

```
df.transpose <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(df$col2, ';')))
```

Comment: I guess I was answering at the same time Majo was commenting.